# Is there an easy way to order a large number of columns without using dplyr::select() in r?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, multiple-columns, organization

I'm working with a very large dataset with lots of columns (400+) and every time I create a new variable or add a new one I have to reorder it. I want it ordered so that all the related variables remain together so I've been using dplyr::select() to reorder things. Yet there are times when I have to go back into my script very early on and add a new variable. When I run the whole code after that, there tends to be one or two variables I forgot to put into preceding select() functions so it goes missing.

I use select() because selecting all the columns between two variables and referencing them by name is super easy (eg, Vfour:Vthreefifty). Do you have any tips for reordering datasets with lots of columns?

Comment: YOu may uses `add_column` at a specific location.  As there is no small reproducible example, it is not clear about the situation

Comment: To avoid accidentally losing columns, add `everthing()` at the end.

Comment: garsimpitoyable, I don't know how we can answer this with any specificity: generally, read [`?dplyr::select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html), specifically its section on *"Useful functions"*, since they help you select multiple columns in a short amount of code; if that's all you needed, then I'd vote this low as "read the documentation". If you need more than that, feel free to provide us something we can gnaw on, otherwise it's too vague or just asking for opinions on ways to manage multiple columns ... opinions are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given no reproducible example but using your 2 column names:

```
df %>%
select(., starts_with('V'))
```

You can then chain `starts_with` as needed.

Other options include:
`ends_with`, `contains`, `matches`

Comment: This is pure gold.

Comment: You don't need the period here - just `select(starts_with())`.

Comment: Very true, I only kept it to represent the place holder for the df